# Why does “go get” sometimes retrieve an outdated commit?

Tags: go, github, go-get

I have created a Go module and put it at `github.com/bronger/abcde`. Erroneously, I declared it in its `go.mod` as `module abcde`.  Therefore, a `go get github.com/bronger/abcde` in a Dockerfile (i.e. without my local copy of the program) fails with

```
#10 0.824 go: downloading github.com/bronger/abcde v0.0.0-20210813180406-8d5688e6c805                                                 #10 0.866 go get: github.com/bronger/abcde@none updating to
#10 0.866       github.com/bronger/abcde@v0.0.0-20210813180406-8d5688e6c805: parsing go.mod:
#10 0.866       module declares its path as: abcde
#10 0.866               but was required as: github.com/bronger/abcde
```

So I corrected the module name in `go.mod` and pushed the result.

Eventually, this works.  However, it may take a long time (30–60 minutes) before `go get` finally detects the change.  The latest incorrect commit is `8d5688e`, which also occurs in the error message above.  Even many minutes after `80c407b` is the latest commit on GitHub, `go get` still complaints about `8d5688e`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Go tools use a proxy provided by the Go Team. This means that changes to modules can be cached for a certain period. You'll be able to find more information about that on their website: https://proxy.golang.org/.

Setting `GOPROXY=off` as an environment variable will disable the use of this proxy.